# Does the equation $\exp{X}=e$ have a discrete set of solutions?

Tags: lie-groups, problem-solving

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $X\in\mathfrak{g}$ an element such that $\exp{X}=e$. Does this equation have a discrete set of solutions, in general? If not, are there any conditions on $G$ so that is does? If this is the case, please provide some references about this topic.

Comment: No, the set of solutions is acted on by $G$ via the adjoint action which typically has infinite orbits. There's no hope unless $G$ is abelian in which case the result is clear.

Comment: I don't understand that question. You are already using $X$ to denote an element of the Lie algebra.

Comment: A semisimple Lie algebra has zero center, so this is the same question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be more clear. I have and equation of the form $\exp{X_0}=\exp{X}$, where $X_0\in\mathfrak{g}$ is a given element such that $\exp{X_0}\in\mathcal{Z}(G)$. I am interested whether the set of $X$ that satisfy this equation is discrete, infinite or not.

Comment: That is precisely the condition necessary to ensure that the set of solutions is acted on by $G$ via the adjoint action, so the answer is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, the matrices
$$X(\theta):=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2\pi i e^{i\theta} \\ 2\pi ie^{-i\theta} & 0\end{pmatrix}\in\mathfrak{su}(2)$$
for $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ have the property that
$$\exp(X(\theta))=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{SU}(2)$$
for all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

In general, the equation $\exp(X)=z$ for $z\in Z_G$ is not discrete, since if there is one solution, say $X$, then $\mathrm{Ad}(g)X$ is another solution for all $g\in G$. Indeed,
$$\exp(\mathrm{Ad}(g)X)=g\exp(X)g^{-1}=gzg^{-1}=zgg^{-1}=z$$
since $z$ commutes with everything. The set $\{\mathrm{Ad}(g)X:g\in G\}$ is called the adjoint orbit of $X$, and is discrete if and only if $X\in Z_{\mathfrak{g}}$ (so $X=0$ when $G$ is semisimple).

Comment: Your last statement is too strong; for example $G$ might be abelian, or more generally might be something like $U(n)$.

Comment: Actually, the last statement convinced me but the exmple not really; my calulations showed that $\exp\left(X\left(\theta \right \right)$ is:
\begin{matrix}
   \cos \left( 1 \right)+\sin \left( 2\pi i \right) & {{e}^{i\theta }}  \\
   {{e}^{-i\theta }} & \cos \left( 1 \right)+\sin \left( 2\pi i \right)  \\
\end{matrix}

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right, thanks. I was assuming $G$ is semisimple.

Comment: @user3257624 I don't know how you got that result, but I still think the example works: [Here is the result on Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixExp%5B%7B%7B0,2Pi+I+Exp%5BI+t%5D%7D,%7B2+Pi+i+Exp%5B-I+t%5D,0%7D%5D).